# How to get data from another system

Tags: abap, bapi

I need to get some data from one system to another.

So far, I used the function module (FM) `RFC_READ_TABLE` where I filled all required fields and got data that I needed from another system's table.

I can't use `RFC_READ_TABLE` in task that I'm working on right now, because of interface agreement. I need to get posting status of invoice; I also found FM `BAPI_BILLINGDOC_GETDETAIL`, but this FM isn't on development system that I'm working on, but it is on system where confidential data are stored. I tried to google stuff, but I couldn't find good example with getting data from another system.

My question is, how do I get data from another system with FM `BAPI_BILLINGDOC_GETDETAIL` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out where was the problem, on our development system there are no BAPI FM and the way how you can get data from another system is that put `DESTINATION` at the end of FM

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_BILLINGDOC_GETDETAIL'
  DESTINATION lv_destination                   "<====== added this line
  EXPORTING
  ...
```

Comment: Please ["DO NOT post images of code"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: RFC is the acronym of Remote Function Call. You may find more information in the ABAP documentation: [Introduction to RFC](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenrfc_intro.htm) and [CALL FUNCTION - RFC](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_function_destination-.htm).